# Search and Click a Button if id Matches or File Name Matches

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-edittext

The basic concept is that I will have multiple buttons for example `Button A`, `Button B`, `Button C` etc.  I also have a `EditText` field at the top of the screen.

What I want to do is if the button name or id matches what I have typed into the `EditText` field then it should click the button automatically.

I would provide the java file for this but it is very basic without anything written inside of it at the moment.

Could anyone kindly help me with the code I need to write in the main java file to match and link button names or id`s please

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `TextWatcher` to get and compare text with button name.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);


 private final TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(yourEditText.getText().toString().equals("button1"))     {

           button1.performClick();
      }
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a method in android studio to create folders in an activity similar to a file explorer and let it search for those names?

Comment: If you are talking about storage then Java provides many structures to store and manipulate data. You can use Array, ArrayList, HashMap etc to store and search names,

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Your code does work but there is one key thing which is missing.  The current code you have written assumes you know the names of the button id.  what happens if someone creates a new folder for example 'x' can that be automatically implemented in the EditText search field?

Comment: in this case you have to create an instance of parent layout, and have to get the ids of its all child. Then you can play with the ids/views.